# Anchor href not working after site is deployed to Win 2012

Tags: html, iframe, href

We just deployed a site onto Windows 2012 (I'm not sure if this is relevent or not). We have a page that contains links to a page that should open in another window.

```
        <a target="_blank" href="../downloader.aspx?ik=3431158">notes.txt</a>
```

Pretty basic!  This code has been in production for over a year and it works as expected: click the link and the downloader.aspx page is opened in another window or tab. We are now testing the site on Win 2012.  Without changing *anything* on this page, it is not working in the test environment.

Other facts that might be relevent: we are using a ModalPopupExtender, the popup is hosting an iframe and the links are on the page in the iframe.

After deploying to Win 2012, this is no longer working. We have tested in IE, FireFox and Chrome - no luck in any browser.

As a workaround, I've added some JavaScript code to handle the click and call window.open() and I get the results I expect.

Has anyone seen this before? Why would a simple href just stop working?

Edit: Pasted the View Source at http://pastebin.com/Z0qv1gY0

Comment: Pull up the page source, is it still being rendered correctly? (Can't imagine why it wouldn't be)

Comment: Have the Network tab open when you click the link, is there a request going through?

Comment: Yes - I should have mentioned, I do see the correct HTML in the View Source. Thanks!

Comment: No - there is no request when I click the link(s)